# Shift and Ctrl in tmux and putty, causing the same effect

Tags: linux, putty, tmux

I'm trying to bind select-pane and next/previous-window to the S-Right/Left and C-Right/Left keys respectively for use with Putty.

Unfortunately I can only seem to get one working at a time. What occurs is that both sets of keys perform the same action when I try them.

My terminal is set to xterm-color256 outside of tmux, and screen inside tmux.
Application Keys Disabled is unticked in putty.

The following is the revelant contents of .tmux.conf

```
setw -g xterm-keys on
bind -n S-Right select-pane -t :.+
bind -n S-Left select-pane -t :.-
bind -n C-Right next-window
bind -n C-Left previous-window
```

Comment: This would be better on SuperUser.com.

Comment: Thanks! I've already read the above but this was probably just a miscategorization mistake. Should have though about superuser before posting here.